On functional equation $f\left(x^2+y^2\right)=f^2\left(x\right)+f^2\left(y\right)$
I got trouble when solving this functional equation:
Find all functions $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ such that $f\left(1\right)>0$ and for all $x,y\in\mathbb{N}$, $$f\left(x^2+y^2\right)=f^2\left(x\right)+f^2\left(y\right)\,.$$

I use the notation $f^2\left(n\right)$ meaning $\left(f\left(n\right)\right)^2$, and in this problem natural number include $0$.
Now I successfully proved $f\left(0\right)=0$, $f\left(1\right)=1$, and $f^2\left(x\right)=f\left(x^2\right)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$. What should I do next to show that $f\left(x\right)=x$?

This question is similar to: Find all functions which satisfy $f(m^2+n^2)=f(m)^2+f(n)^2$ $\forall\space m,n\in\Bbb{N}$ and $f(1)>0$. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
